# How do I adjust the default references for a new project?

Tags: visual-studio

Maybe I'm not searching correctly, but I can't find out how to configure the default set of references for a new project.

I don't use System.Data and System.Xml for EVERY project.  It seems like something I should be able to configure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of references that are added to a new project is determined by the particular template of the project.  Project templates are a fairly generic concept and there is no way to control items like the set of references.

What you can do though is create a new project template which is a mirror of the normal template and remove those references from the project file.  Simply copy the template from it's default location (in the ProjectTemplatesCache folder under Visual Studio) to the user specific folder under "Visual Studio 2008" in My Documents.  You'll also want to rename it to be distinct in the window.  After you do this the new template will start showing up on the new project dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The project templates, which include the references, are stored in ZIP files corresponding to the project type.

You can make a backup copy and then modify the original template according to your needs.

The exact path will depend on your version of Visual Studio.  I'm at an old PC with VS2005 installed and found this path:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033